# jQuery.getJSON with JSONP is returning the same data for different calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery.getJSON() to hit the same web service three times in a row with different parameters. Then I'm drawing charts with the data I receive. The problem though is quite basic, it doesn't have to do with the chart at all. When I get the data in my callback function it is not consistently the "right" data. For example:

```
var URL1 = http://mysite.com/myAPI/metrics?type=pageloads&date=02022012&callback=?
var URL2 = http://mysite.com/myAPI/metrics?type=formsubmissions&date=02232012&callback=?
var URL3 = http://mysite.com/myAPI/metrics?type=uniqueusers&date=02022012&callback=?

var getDataAndDraw = function(metricURL, chartDiv) {
    $.getJSON(metricURL, function(data){
        console.log(data.metricName);

        // i do my charting here
    });
};

getDataAndDraw(URL1, 'pageloadsDiv');
getDataAndDraw(URL2, 'formsubmissionsDiv');
getDataAndDraw(URL3, 'uniqueuserDiv');
```

Sometimes I get the right 3 graphs and the console displays the expected metric names. But sometimes I get some mix of the same ones. For example... I'll be displaying the pageloads metrics twice and uniqueuser metrics once and console will show that the data for pageloads was returned twice and uniqueuser once.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Answer (score 3):

The AJAX requests are likely being cached. This code should fix that problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

Comment: Not sure why it started working with this solution, but now it is not. I think it was a fluke (and a lack of extensive testing on my part). I'm looking at the setting for cache and it doesn't seem like it should affect this situation for a couple reasons...   **1.** cache is false by default for jsonp requests;    **2.** my 3 links have different url's so caching them would cause them to reuse their own data they got last time, not one of the other url's data which is the behavior I'm seeing